# What plants in are in the patch of ground behind my Beijing apartment?

Tags: identification, urban-gardening

Can anyone help identify any of these plants..

1.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

2.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

3.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

4.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

5.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

6.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

7.[image: various shrubs and weeds in an urban setting]

I live in Beijing, and I am considering commandeering an unused patch of dirt behind my apartment building to grow a few flowers or vegetables or herbs. While I am searching around to find which plants are native to the North China Plain, I also want to figure out what plants I should "remove" from the patch of dirt. Most likely I will only take a few square feet in the corner of the dirt patch.

Comment: Generally speaking we try for identification questions for one plant at a time however there is a good answer already

Comment: @kevinskio Oh my gosh, I'm so sorry. I didn't really that I would be violating community norms.

Answer (score 1):

Although it can be difficult to identify plants from photos without flowers, I think I can help with a few of them.

Pictures 1 and 5- Some small bamboo and a blooming honeysuckle vine (*Lonicera* sp.). Picture 5 shows another, much larger, bamboo.

Picture 3 - A Tree of Heaven (*Ailanthus altissima*), the same small bamboo, as in picture 1, and a blooming honeysuckle vine.

Picture 4 - A Tree of Heaven that's been decapitated in the last year or so.

Pictures 6 and 7 - A collection of what I would call weeds; however, they could be escaped herbs that I just don't recognize. Most of the ones against the wall resemble a lettuce going to seed. There is a rayless composite in the left side of picture 6 that resembles horseweed, which would make it a noxious weed.

I suspect that the bamboo will be difficult to keep out of your little patch of garden.

Comment: I would say everything shown could be considered a weed ; likely all volunteers.

Comment: Oops I thought picture 2 was rose of some kind...

Comment: I also thought it might be a rose, but the leaves looked a bit iffy. Without flowers, I won't be able to make even an attempt at an identification.